# How to hide fullscreen apps in MacOS programmatically

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, desktop-application, nsworkspace

I'm trying to make an app that would hide other windows/apps with a certain interval, but I'm stuck with hiding fullscreen app windows using NSWorkspace and NSRunningApplication classes.

Is there any way to exit fullscreen mode programmatically using public APIs? If not, what private APIs I need to look at to achieve this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can get around sandboxing, you can use AppleScript to tell System Events to tell the process in question to set its `attribute "AXFullScreen" of window 1 to false`.

Comment: I believe that would make the app non-AppStorable?

Comment: I have no idea, but you said were willing to use "private APIs", so the App Store is already out of the question. You can't have your cake and eat it too.